# jenkins installation on Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS -- running into problems

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-12.04, jenkins

```
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      jenkins
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 57.8 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 63.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ jenkins 1.529 [57.8 MB]
    Fetched 57.8 MB in 18s (3,198 kB/s)                                                                               
    Selecting previously unselected package jenkins.
    (Reading database ... 220980 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking jenkins (from .../archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb) ...
    dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite '/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war', which is also in package jenkins-common 1.424.6+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.529_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't experienced this myself, but this looks like you already have an older jenkins. Try this (hope it helps... no guarantees :-):

```
> apt-get purge jenkins-common
> apt-get install jenkins
```

The purge should remove the old package including any configuration files, and the install will install the new one.